How can we make a secondary file group READ_ONLY without affecting connected users in SQL Server?
Let's assume I am working on SQL Server. Currently, the scenario is that I have a database, and that database has a primary file group and a secondary file group. Now, dynamically, via procedure, I want to create a new file group and mark the secondary file group as read-only without any connected user effect.
So, could you please provide me with a way to do this?
set @sqlexecute = n'exec master.sys.sp_executesql '+
        'n''alter database '+quotename(@dbname)+' modify filegroup '+@makereadonlyfilegroup+' read_only;''

I have tried this above code to make filegroup as a ready_only.
Database state cannot be changed while other users are using the database

The short answer is - you can't. The docs say "To change this state, you must have exclusive access to the database." So you'll either have to wait for that condition to happen organically (unlikely), you'll have to boot everyone out, or commit to not having that FG be read-only.
